# How to read multiple inputs on same line in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I'm trying to read all the input from one line, using scanner, then take the values and find the second largest. I would use an array **BUT** I am not allowed. You are supposed to enter 10 integers, hit enter and evaluate them.

Something like this:

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 ENTER

Second highest number is: 90
```

I can't manage to solve it at all. It should be easy but I have no idea.

```
public class SecondLargest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
        int largest = 0;
        int secondLargest = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter integers: ");
        int numbers = sc.nextInt();
        largest = numbers;

        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            if (numbers > largest) {
                secondLargest = largest;
                largest = numbers;
            } else if (numbers > secondLargest) {
                secondLargest = numbers;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Second largest number is: " + secondLargest);
        sc.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you enter all 10 integers first and then press Enter? Or do you enter the first number, press Enter, second Number, press Enter, and so on?

Comment: 10 in a row. Edited my post for better clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with assigning the first scanned integer to `largest` and `secondLargest` variables and then process the remaining nine integers in a loop as follows:

```
num = sc.nextInt();
if (num > largest) {
    secondLargest = largest;
    largest = num;
}
```

**Demo**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SecondLargest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter 10 integers separated by single spaces: ");

        // Scan the first integer and assign it to largest and secondLargest
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int largest = num;
        int secondLargest = largest;

        // Input 9 more integers
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            num = sc.nextInt();
            if (num > largest) {
                secondLargest = largest;
                largest = num;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The second largest number is: " + secondLargest);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter 10 integers separated by single spaces: 10 23 4 12 80 45 78 90 105 7
The second largest number is: 90
```

**Note:** This is just a sample program assuming that the input is in the correct format. I leave it to you to work on how to deal with the wrong input. It will be a good exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
**In this code I've used BufferedReader class which is faster than Scanner 
Class as well as have large buffer of 8KB while Scanner has only 1KB.**
*/
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Second_Highest {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[] s=br.readLine().split(" ");
    int a[]=new int[10];
    int max=Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        a[i]=Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
        if(a[i]>max)
        {
            max=a[i];
        }
    }
    int secondmax=Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>secondmax && a[i]<max)
        {
            secondmax=a[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.print(secondmax);
 }   
}
```

Comment: You do not need an array to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To read single line input, You can do this simply by eating the (\n) which is new line in Java.

Input : 1 2 3

```
\\Create the object of Scanner Class
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = sc.nextInt();
int c = sc.nextInt();

// this will eat the new line and move forward for other inputs.
sc.nextLine()
```

To read in a loop or to store at 2D array.

Input :
1 2 3
3 4 5
6 7 8

```
//... do the above declaration of array

for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   for( int j = 0; j < m; j++){
      arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt()
    } 
   sc.nextLine(); // you need to eat the \n here. 
}
```

This will work perfectly.

Now you should be able to get the input easily in a single line.

Comment: You do not need an array to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet can be used to take multiple Integer Input on same line.

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);    // Declare and Initialize Scanner
while(sc.hasNext())                    // While the input has data execute
    System.out.println(sc.nextInt());  // nextInt() method is used to take Integer data
```

For Multiple String input on same line separated by white space or a comma,
we can use the following snippet

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[,\\s+]");
```

Comment: The issue for me here is that it takes nextInt, so it never really prints the first int.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class m1{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scannerscan = new Scanner(System.in);
Stringnum = scan.nextLine();
String[] strs = num.split("\\s+");
int[] arrs = new int[strs.length];
for(inti=0;i<strs.length;i++)
{
String stringnum = strs[i];
arrs[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringnum);
if(arrs[i]%2==0){
System.out.print(" ");
}
else{
System.out.print(arrs[i]);
}
}
scan.close();
}
}
```

Comment: This is a program of a prime no. in which the input and out will in single line for multiple inputs taken by user. input :1 2 3 4 5  output 1 3 5